# Access variable in Backbone View from Backbone Router

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

My router

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ':*':'home',
            'home' : 'home',
            'home/:a' : 'home',
            '*whatever' : '404'

        },
        home: function (a) {
            document.title = siteTitle + ' - Home';
            homePage = new HomePage;
            homePage.render(a);
        },
        404: function(){
            document.title = siteTitle + ' - 404';
            fofPage = new FoFPage;
            fofPage.render();
        }

    });
```

My home view

```
var HomePage = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender');
            var _this = this;
            this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function (render) {
                _this.beforeRender();
                render();
                _this.afterRender();
                return _this;
            });
        },

        beforeRender: function () {
            console.log('beforeRender');
        },

        el: $('#indexcontent'),

        template: _.template(homeHTML, {}),

        render: function (a) {
            (a == null) ? Backbone.history.navigate('home'): Backbone.history.navigate('home/' + a);
            console.log('Passed parameter is ' + a);
            this.$el.html(this.template);

        },

        afterRender: function () {
            $('pre code').each(function (i, block) {
                hljs.highlightBlock(block);
            });
            console.log('afterRender');
        }
    });
```

I am trying to catch that variable `a` from router to view. But it shows undefined in my console. I tried fiddling with the variable `options` in the initialize but no luck. 
Thanks

Comment: PS: https://bitbucket.org/sizil/backbone-requireboiler/overview this is the sample boilet plate of Backbone JS and RequireJS, if anyone wants. This is my first repo so pardon my sins.

Comment: Hardcoding ` el: $('#indexcontent')` is a bad idea. That option is supposed to be dynamic. You can simply decorate the default element with an `id` instead

Comment: I agree hardcoding element is a bad idea. But for this particular skeleton, i need to hardcode since my index page is blank with a loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ':*':'home',
            'home' : 'home',
            'home/:a' : 'home',
            '*whatever' : '404'

        },
        home: function (a) {
            document.title = siteTitle + ' - Home';
            homePage = new HomePage({route: a});
            homePage.render();
        },
        404: function(){
            document.title = siteTitle + ' - 404';
            fofPage = new FoFPage;
            fofPage.render();
        }

    });
```

View

```
var HomePage = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = options;
            _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender');
            var _this = this;
            this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function (render) {
                _this.beforeRender();
                render(_this.options['route']);
                _this.afterRender();
                return _this;
            });
        },

        beforeRender: function () {
            console.log('beforeRender');
        },

        el: $('#indexcontent'),

        template: _.template(homeHTML, {}),

        render: function (a) {
            (a == null) ? Backbone.history.navigate('home'): Backbone.history.navigate('home/' + a);
            console.log('Passed parameter is ' + a);
            this.$el.html(this.template);

        },

        afterRender: function () {
            $('pre code').each(function (i, block) {
                hljs.highlightBlock(block);
            });
            console.log('afterRender');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

While you found an answer, I will explain why your initial code wasn't working and even more.

## Why passing to `render` doesn't work?

Because you're overriding the `render` function in the `initialize` function with a wrapped version, using the [underscore's `wrap`](http://underscorejs.org/#wrap) function.

It could work, but you'd need to take the parameter into account when wrapping:

```
this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function(render, a) {
    this.beforeRender();
    render.call(this, a); // here, pass the argument
    this.afterRender();
    return this;
});
```

Also notice that you don't need `var _this = this` as you're just replacing a *member* function and the context is applied automatically when called. Same thing for `_.bindAll` which is useless here.

## The easier way

That wrap thing is unnecessary, it's only complexifying the `HomePage` view without any benefits or added features.

**The only thing you'd need:**

```
var HomePage = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#indexcontent'),
```

You can ignore the *options* param (the `{}`)

```
    template: _.template(homeHTML),

    initialize: function(options) {
```

if you want to pass options to initialize, use one of the following patterns:

```
        this.options = options || {}; // make sure it's an object.
```

or, better, make sure it's a **copy** of the object, with default values.

```
        this.options = _.extend({
            route: "default-value"
        }, options);
    },

    beforeRender: function() {
        console.log('beforeRender');
    },

    render: function(route) {
        this.beforeRender();
```

Do the redirection in the router, it's his role.

```
        // (a == null) ? Backbone.history.navigate('home'): Backbone.history.navigate('home/' + a);

        console.log('Passed parameter is ' + route || this.options.route);
```

The [underscore's `_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function returns a function, so you need to call it.

```
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        this.afterRender();
        return this;
    },

    afterRender: function() {
```

Avoid the global jQuery function and prefer scoping your search to the view element and its children with `this.$(selector)`.

```
        this.$('pre code').each(function(i, block) {
            hljs.highlightBlock(block);
        });
        console.log('afterRender');
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Emile! I just noticed i've been seen u around alot lately! :D And yeah thanks for helping me, i began to write this new pseudo code thanks to your answer in my last question (Javascript SQL). Couple of insomniac nights and i know Backbone.

Comment: Although i wanted to try my hands on Angular and Some impressive graphic designs too. See you around.

Comment: @unkn0wn yeah I mostly hang around [tag:backbone.js] questions